# Issue with nodejs and npm installation

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to install nodejs for Tableau extensions
Below are the commands used to install.
npm install
npm run build
After installation getting the below error and warning message.Please suggest
Error1:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\extensions-api-main\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Warnings-2:
npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
npm WARN old lockfile   errno: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands

```
npm config set strictSSL false
```

**OR**

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: After running npm config set strictSSL false this command now getting the below error                                   C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs